# The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated

Tags: logging, travis-ci

My travis build appears to be creating an enormous number of empty log outputs. This only happens when I run it on travis, but not when I run any tests manually on my local machine.

My Travis file looks as follows:
https://github.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker/blob/master/.travis.yml

```
language: python


python:
  - "3.6"

os:
  - linux

install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then MINICONDA_OS=Linux; else MINICONDA_OS=MacOSX; fi
  - wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-$MINICONDA_OS-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p "$HOME"/miniconda
  - source "$HOME"/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no --set auto_update_conda false
  - pip install requirements.txt
  - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  - export COVERAGE_DIR=":$HOME/htmlcov"
  - printenv | sort

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# command to run tests
script: pytest --log-cli-level=warning

after_success:
  - codecov
```

The output can be seen here:
https://travis-ci.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker/builds/134819176
It ends with "The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated."

Any suggestions are appreciated how I can avoid this large log outpu that seems to be coming from nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

https://travis-ci.community/t/the-job-exceeded-the-maximum-log-length-and-has-been-terminated/3635

> The error message is pretty clear.
>
> Reduce the number of output that your build produces.
>
> E.g. in your case, reduce the number of warnings that it generates since they take up the bulk of the output.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html

---

I have same error. But i fixed my problem by cutting output logs.